# Why Eigen values of adajcency matrix are actually the sentence scores in Textrank

Tags: python, nlp, eigenvector, pagerank, summarization

Here is the route for TextRank:

1. Document to be summarized expressed as tf-idf matrix
2. (tf-idf matrix)*(tf-idf matrix).Transpose = Adjacency matrix of some graph whose vertices are
   actually the sentences of above document
3. Page rank is applied on this graph -> returns PR values of each sentence

Now, **this PR values are actually Eigen values of that adjacency matrix**
What is the physical meaning or intuition behind this.?

**Why Eigen values are actually the ranks ?**

Here is the link for Page Rank:
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/courses/BIB/pagerank.htm

Here is an extract from above page: 
**PageRank or PR(A) can be calculated using a simple iterative algorithm, and corresponds to the principal eigenvector of the normalized link matrix of the web.**

Link for TextRank:
https://joshbohde.com/blog/document-summarization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, your question is a bit mistaken. The eignevalues are *not* the scores. Rather, the *entries of the stationary eigenvector* are the scores.

Textrank works on a [graphical approach to words](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/papers/mihalcea.emnlp04.pdf). It has a number of variations, but they have the following common steps:

1. Create a weighted graph where the vertices are entities (words or sentences), and the weights are the transition probabilities between entities.
2. Find the [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) associated with the graph, and score each entity according to its stationary distribution.

In this case, the graph is built as follows. First, a matrix is built where the rows are sentences and the columns are words. The entries of the matrix are specified by TF-IDF. To find the similarity between sentences, the normalized matrix is multiplied by its transform. This is because, for each two sentences and a word, there is a similarity between the sentences based on the product of the TF-IDF of the word in each sentence, and we need to sum up over all words. If you think about it a bit, summing up the products is exactly what matrix multiplication by the transpose does.

So now we have a stochastic matrix *P* which can be interpreted as the probability of transition from sentence *i* to sentence *j*. The score is the stationary distribution *x*, which means that

*P x = x = 1 x*.

This means that *x* is the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue 1. By the [Perron-Frobenius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), this eigenvector exists under some mild conditions, and 1 is the largest eigenvalue. This last part is basically Pagerank.

Comment: Thanks .... 
So, we get some eigenvector using that above equation...BUT the doubt is: **How is finding some eigenvector relates to PageRank algorithm..?** whats the intuition/physical sense of this relation... ?. Could you please elaborate on this

Comment: The last part *is* Pagerank, basically: it finds the importance by solving for the stationary eigenvector of the stochastic matrix *P*. Text rank basically borrows this idea for sentence ranking applications, and specifies how to build *P* for this case.

Comment: And how is it that P matrix is stochastic ( tf-idf values can be anything and might not add to 1) ?

Comment: @mach I explained that in the answer: it's the product of the *normalized* TF-IDF matrix by itself, with the rationale I outlined.

Comment: Is it possible to think it visually: P matrix acts on x (which is actually PR vector) but it doesnt change (since it is an eigenvector), that means PR vector doesnt  change... How else to understand this intuition visually ?

Comment: @mach Yes, that's basically it. A visual way (which I'm unsure is more helpful) is to think of a graph where the edges specify transition probabilities (that's *P*). Now you need to ask what are the node probabilities that would fit in with these edge probabilities. Markov chains are not the most intuitive things always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122560/discussion-between-mach-and-ami-tavory).